Serilog WithDestructuringDepth vs ToMaximumDepth
How does DestructuringOptionsBuilder.WithDestructuringDepth() actually work in Serilog.Exceptions? When I change this value I do not see any difference of logged properties.
The difference is when applying configuration using LoggerConfiguration.Destructure.ToMaximumDepth() - the depth is indeed limited to passed value
